# Week of month, month of year,year

Tags: vb.net, datetime, dayofweek, weekday

I would like to check Week of month, month of year and year but I have a problem with week of month
here is code:

```
Public Class BMW
    Public Shared Function GetWeekNumber() As Integer
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)

        Dim span As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
        Return (CInt(span.TotalDays) \ 7) + 1

        If span.TotalDays = 1 Then

            SendKeys.Send("{1}")
            MsgBox(span.TotalDays)

        Else
            MsgBox("chybi1")
end if
end function
```

Comment: use datetime.dayofweek(). Set the date value to the first of the month and check which day of the week the first is. then you can figure out how to do the second week

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function GetWeekNumber(ByVal datum As Date) As Integer

    Dim weeknumber = Math.Floor(datum.Day / 7 + +1)

    SendKeys.Send(weeknumber)
    Return weeknumber

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is your friend:

```
Private Function GetWeekNumber() As Integer
    Dim span As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1)
    Return (CInt(span.TotalDays) \ 7) + 1
End Function
```

I'm not even sure this is what you are looking for..

Comment: Ok , but when I detect week of mont is first and after detect send a key for example A for second week od month send key B and next it is possible?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Alessandro how can I call this function , how can I get number from this.? thank you

Comment: Dim a as integer = GetWeekNumber()